# Could someone help solving the following ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am encountering a problem of solving an ordinary differential equation for an initial value problem in the form of

$$y'(t)+ay(t)+b\ln(y(t))=c$$

where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are constants, and $y(0)=y_0$.

Could someone help me find a general solution?

Comment: Not sure how to solve it but Mathematica gave me: $$t=\int_1^{y}(c-ax-b\log x)^{-1}dx$$ so I don't think its doable in elementary functions.

Comment: Mathematica gave you the integral form of the same equation @IanMiller. The only possible avenue I see for analytic progress would be assuming $b \ll a,c$ and treating the problem using regular perturbation theory.

Comment: I was implying that Mathematica couldn't do much with it so here ends my attempt. :)